# join tables in a loop sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

say that I have a base table `BaseTable` and a list of ancillary_tables [`SupportTable1`, `SupportTable2`, `SupportTable3`], and I want to do something like

```
        with session_maker.begin() as session:
            stmt = session.query(BaseTable, SupportTable1, SupportTable2, SupportTable3)\
                   .join(SupportTable1, SupportTable1.base_id==BaseTable.id)\
                   .join(SupportTable2, SupportTable2.base_id== BaseTable.id)\
                   .join(SupportTable3, SupportTable3.base_id==BaseTable.id)
```

However, I would like to make a function `merge_tables(base_table, list_of_ancillary_tables)` that allows the user to input 0, 1, 2, or all ancillary tables. Therefore, I think that I need to do it in a loop, something like

```
        with self.session_maker.begin() as session:
            tables = [base_table] + list_of_ancillary_tables
            stmt = session.query(tables)
            for table in list_of_ancillary_tables:
                stmt = stmt.join(table, table.base_id==base_table.id)
```

The above statement does not work and is just for demonstration purpose, looking for a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case a quick fix might be to unpack the list of table objects inside of the query object.

```
        with self.session_maker.begin() as session:
            tables =  list_of_ancillary_tables
            stmt = session.query(base_table,*tables)
            for table in list_of_ancillary_tables:
                # or include the base_table in the list but skip it in the loop
                stmt = stmt.join(table, table.base_id==base_table.id)

# a stmt.filter(table.attr == base_table.attr) could also work
```

```
#Alternative the bottom loop if you have a specific attribute in mind
# assuming base_table is kept out
 for table in list_of_ancillary_tables:
      stmt = stmt.join(table, getattr(table,attr)==getattr(base_table,attr))
```

However, know that this approach might give you a "columns are ambiguous error" if the tables either share non foreign-key columns that have the same name or contain more than one foreign key. But the fact that you are explicitly stating the join condition should help avoid that.